# accidentally removed android dependencies folder

Tags: android, android-library

I accidentally removed the library: "android dependencies". Is there a way to retrieve it or import/download? A person suggested me to "go to source and say order import export for all libraries you need except the android defualt libs.." but I don't understand exactly what it means. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: well..i did clean the project. and select Build Project under the Project menu. but it does nothing..

Comment: is there a such option for rebuild?

Comment: Try this. Right click on project > Properties > Java build path > Add library > Android classpath container > Select your project > Finish

Comment: it doesn't do anything when i follow the steps. am i missing anything please? thank you kindly

Comment: Did you see your project name in "Select your project" in Android container ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at project.properties file. You will see android sdk version(Example : target=android-4) which you used. And then  Project -> Right Click -> Java Build Path -> (Your SDK folder -> platform -> android-x(your api version number) -> android.jar(Select this)). And clean your project. Try this.

Comment: There are steps missing here. When right clicking the project I get Build Path option not Java build path but still what do I do then? Do I have to add the android.jar as external archive?

Comment: In case someone has the same problem I had to restart eclipse after adding the above jar as external archive. "Clean" didn't do the job.

Comment: @konpsych in my case I can still start running the app without restarting, even though the Android Dependencies didn't show up; and yes restarting make the thing appear again

Answer (score 15):

[Another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779868/what-is-android-dependencies-remove-it-from-build-path-classnotfoundexception) contains solution to this problem.And you do not have to restart eclipse.

Just right click project->Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
   and your Android Dependencies folder appears.