# Android dependencies error after renaming project

Tags: android, eclipse

I renamed my Project:

[image]

after that i got the red callsign at my Project(which you see in the first Image) and this:

[image]

also my projectproperties says this but i'm not sure if this was also the case before renaming:

[image]

even that the path is(!) spelled correctly.

I referenced the libaries to my Project:

[image]

But i'm not able to fix the Problem. Still he doesn't recognize the Facebook and GPS libs in my Project..

I also checked this:

[Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

this:

[accidentally removed android dependencies folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954960/accidentally-removed-android-dependencies-folder)

and this...

[Completely renaming a project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935907/completely-renaming-a-project-in-eclipse)

but nothing did the trick.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a full clean/refresh of all the projects inside your workspace?

Comment: @bonnyz of course after every new Approach i did that

Comment: Maybe is simpler to create a new project with the correct name and than copy all the files from the old project ;)

Comment: @bonnyz sounds like the last Approach. how can i accomblish that it the easiest way? Do i Need to copy all the files one by one or is there some easier way to accomblish this?

Comment: @bonnyz because i have a lot of classes and layouts and drawables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(following up after some comments)

If your project is broken after a refactor and you are going crazy to figure out what's wrong you can consider to **create a fresh new project**.

**Create an empty project starting from the existing one is really simple**, just follow this steps:

1. Create a new project with the desidered name
2. Copy *oldProject/**src**/* to *newProject/**src**/*
3. Copy *oldProject/**res**/* to *newProject/**res**/*
4. Copy *oldProject/**libs**/* to *newProject/**libs**/*
5. Copy *oldProject/**AndroidManifest.xml*** to *newProject/**AndroidManifest.xml***
6. Check that your project's **classpath** is set correctly, same for other **dependecies**.
7. **Refresh** all the projects in the workspace (one by one)
8. **Clean** (yes, it's always a good idea)
9. **Build all**

Answer (score 0):

For each of your projects, verify dependencies in project references & java build path:

1. File -> Properties
2. "Java Build Path"
   verify, that all projects, referenced by current project, are added.
3. "Project references"
   verify, that all projects, referenced by current project, are checked.