# What is the purpose of the Android Private Libraries, Referenced Libraries and Android Dependies in android project hierarchy?

Tags: android, libraries, android-library

I want to know the exact use of **Android Private Libraries**, **Referenced Libraries** and **Android Dependencies** in an android project hierarchy?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Android Private Libraries** - Android libraries allows one to store source code and resources which are used by several other Android projects. The Android Development Tools(ADT) compile the content of library into the Android project by creating a JAR file. Using libraries, help you to structure your application code. Also more and more important Open Source libraries are available for Android. Understanding library projects is therefore important for every Android programmer.

**Referenced Libraries** - Referenced Libraries include all the necessary external JAR libraries that the project requires to function.

**Android Dependencies** - Android Dependencies is a virtual folder where Eclipse shows what JAR files the project depends on. It's not a physical folder; you won't find it on your hard disk.
Deleting this folder would destroy your project.

References - 
[Android Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779915/2451524),
[Referenced Libraries](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29),
[Android Private Libraries](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: Isn't the "Android Private Libraries" also considered external JAR libraries? Then, what's the difference between "Android Private Libraries" and "Referenced Libraries"?

Answer (score -2):

**Android Private Libraries**:Basically the android-support-v4.jar need to be in Referenced Libraries by right click, Build Path.., Add to Path. Then in Referenced Libraries,
right click properties on android-support-v4 and set the sources.Taken from Android Support Library (v4). Getting the source and attaching it 
to the library/jar in Eclipse.

**Android Reference library**:If you are adding references to multiple libraries, note that you can set their relative priority (and merge order) by selecting a 
library and using the Up and Down controls. The tools merge the referenced libraries with your application starting from lowest priority 
(bottom of the list) to highest (top of the list). If more than one library defines the same resource ID, the tools select the resource 
from the library with higher priority. The application itself has highest priority and its resources are always used in preference to identical 
resource IDs defined in libraries.

**Android Dependencies**:this folder show dependencies between JAR files and project.